# mod_expires won't work after enabled in apache2.conf

Tags: server, apache2

[After reading here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/apache-module-mod-expires?tsrc=error_page), I put the following code block in my `apache2.conf`:

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</Filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

I then restarted Apache and flushed all CMS cache, and ran [a GPI test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), in which I still get the following error, indicating that the module doesn't work:

> Leverage browser caching
>
> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

I thought the reason is that `mod_cache` isn't on so I did `a2enmod cache` and then pasted in the Vhost of my site the following code and restarted Apache. It didn't help as well, and I still get the same error in GPI:

```
    CacheQuickHandler off
    CacheLock on
    CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
    CacheLockMaxAge 5
    CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is what might be missing to enable mod_expires, why won't it work?

Comment: Did you enable the `headers` and `expires` modules?  `sudo a2enmod expires headers`. Can you share with the link you are testing? Are you adding those configs in the `.htaccess` file? or are you adding them to the virtual host config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` ?

Comment: expires seems to be already enabled (maybe because I pasted the codeblock in apache2.conf), but I now enabled headers as well and restarted Apache. I try to avoid adding anything to .htaccess and doing it as much as possible from apache2.conf because .htaccess is being auto updated once a while from the CMS. I added nothing (in regarding to expires) to the Virtual host.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=iw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbenia.biz%2F&tab=desktop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `expires` module requires the `headers` module to work.

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Other than that, your configuration seems fine.

But in order to stop PageSpeed Insights from complaining, you just need to increase the expiry time of your resources from 2 days to a value greater or equal to 7 days.

You just need to modify the following line:

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

From the [PageSpeed Insights docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching):

> We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently.

Comment: Awesome!
I had installed WordPress using the WordPress on Ubuntu Image on DigitalOcean. After installed W3 Total Cache plugin and even manually entering the caching rules in .htaccess the files served didn't have any headers related to caching, doing this solved my problem!